# Behavior of "enter/next" key on mobile browsers when entering into a number field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, mobile

I've got a single line of code (no forms involved) here:

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="9999999" id="inSku" name="inSku">
```

Before, I was using `type="text"`, but on mobile browsers that gave the full keyboard by default and the box in question only takes number inputs. Logically, the mobile browsers will change to an only-number keyboard when they focus on a `type="number"` field - however, I am currently relying on a little bit of `jQuery` to handle the submission of the content of the form. Here's that code:

```
$("#inSku").keyup(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        ringItem();
    }
});
```

The problem here being that on the stock android phone keyboard (and I'm assuming a good number of other mobile browsers) - when using the "number" keyboard, the enter key that is on the regular alphanumeric android keyboard has changed to a "next" button. This button in my case takes the text input and sticks it in the address field, not exactly ideal. Is there any way to harness the next button on the keyboard and get that to execute my other javascript function?

Comment: For the people who come here looking for the exact keycode as well: The keycode of the *next* key on Chrome Android is `9` (which is the tab key on desktop keyboards).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
 $('#inSku').keyup(function (e) {
   alert('Key pressed: ' + e.keyCode);
 });
```

The idea here is to press the `next` button and find that key code. Once you do, you can add it to your logic like `if (event.keyCode === 13 || event.keyCode === ...)`. You can add as many qualifiers as you need to to support multiple keypads and devices.

Comment: On Android 4.2.x, on a Samsung S4, it works only with `keydown` event, not `keyup`.

Comment: In my case OnePlus 6 doesn't seem to trigger keydown or keyup event for the 'next' button