# How can we capture a mobile device "Next" button key press in Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, ios, dom-events

Most keys on a mobile smartphone keyboard produce a keycode with the following code, however the "Next" and "Prev." buttons do not:

```
$('#txtRegMobileNumber2').keydown(function (e) {
    alert('Key pressed: ' + e.keyCode);
});
```

How can I capture the "Next" button press (equivalent to the arrows in iOS) in Javascript?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19016548/behavior-of-enter-next-key-on-mobile-browsers-when-entering-into-a-number-fiel) other question may be a duplicate, but seeing as how the code does not work for me I still need help. I've tried using `e.which` and `keyup()` to no avail.

Comment: I have had luck in the past with keyup over keydown.  Have you tried that?  From what I remember keydown was being skipped by some devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are concerned in capturing when the user moved away from your text field, maybe consider the `blur()` JavaScript event?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/blur

Comment: you should not use w3schools as reference - use MDN instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/blur

Comment: This is practically the approach I ended up taking.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps a bit late answer but this issue can be solved with adding `inputmode` property to your input and setting it's value to 'search' thanks to that the "Go"/"Next" button on the keyboard is replaced by "Enter" that behaves the same way as normal enter button on a traditional keyboard.

```
<input id="txtRegMobileNumber2" inputmode="search"
```

Docs:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/inputmode

Answer (score -1):

Use remote debugging with console output and press those keys to get the code.

Comment: Good suggestion, however, this does not seem to solve the issue if you can not capture the event using javascript, since javascript is most likely what will be used to handle the event.